# Is it correct to omit the definite article before the word "dad"/"father "and "mom"/"mother" when referring to one's parents?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Is natural to omit the definite article before *mom*/*mother* and *dad*/*father* meaning one's mom or dad. For example:

> **Mom** says that I don't have to clean my room.
>
> I will ask **dad** if I can take his car.

By *dad* and *mom* I mean my mom and dad.

Comment: Which articles are you talking about? There are none in your examples. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples, no - you would not use the definite article "*the*".

You are using "Mom" and "Dad" as *proper nouns*, and in written form they should be *capitalised*. Most people do not call their parents by their forenames, so "Mom and Dad" are substituting for these.

> **Mom** says that I don't have to clean my room.
>
> I will ask **Dad** if I can take his car.

In *most* situations where you are referring to your mother and father, you would say "**my** mom" or "**my** dad" to make it clear you are referring to your own parents. When you refer to them this way, there is no need to capitalise them.

> I will ask **my dad** if I can take his car.

We only use the definite article "the" when it is clear which specific thing/person/group you are referring to, and as there are many, many moms and dads in the world, "the" wouldn't necessarily point to yours.

An example where you might use the definite article with "mom and dad" is if you had established a context in which there is only one set of parents, for example:

> How do you think the mom and dad *in this story* felt?